# sscanf for this type of string

Tags: c++, parsing, scanf

I'm not quite sure even after reading the documentation how to do this with sscanf.

Here is what I want to do:
given a string of text:

Read up to the first 64 chars or until space is reached
Then there will be a space, an = and then another space.
Following that I want to extract another string either until the end of the string or if 8192 chars are reached. I would also like it to change any occurrences in the second string of "\n" to the actual newline character.

I have: "%64s = %8192s" but I do not think this is correct.

Thanks

Ex:

element.name = hello\nworld

Would have string 1 with element.name and string2 as

```
hello
world
```

Comment: There are several unclarities: "either until the end of the string" == "either until the end of the line"? "actual newline character"??

Comment: As it stands, this task cannot be solved by `sscanf`, as it does not differentiate between a space and a newline.

Comment: sscanf is rarely the answer to any input verification problem. Read the line into a string and use normal string manip or a regex to verify the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do recommend std::regex for this, but apart from that, you should be fine with a little error checking:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char s1[65];
    char s2[8193];
    if (2!=std::scanf("%64s = %8192s", s1, s2))
        puts("oops");
    else
        std::printf("s1 = '%s', s2 = '%s'\n", s1, s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `%8192s` will stop at the first blank, which is probably not the result required.  You might be able to get away with `%8192[^\n]` (up to 8 KiB of non-newline characters, though.  I'm assuming that 'to end of string' means 'to end of line'.  Converting characters backslash-n to newline will be a separate operation.

Answer (score 1):

Your format string looks right to me; however, sscanf will not change occurences of "\n" to anything else.  To do that you would then need to write a loop that uses strtok or even just a simple for loop evaluating each character in the string and swapping it for whatever character you prefer.  You will also need to evaluate the sscanf return value to determine if the 2 strings were indeed scanned correctly.  sscanf returns the number of field successfully scanned according to your format string.

@sehe shows the correct usage of sscanf including the check for the proper return value.